# How to write an element of $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

There is a  proof of $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) $ being isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^*$ ([see the answer by my forum friend Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2985049/850314), also I found the same statement in a book). The proof I tried is :

Here, we have the homomorphism $f: GL(2,\mathbf R)\to\mathbf R^*$, defined as $A\mapsto \det A$ where $A \in GL(2,\mathbf R) $.

If $B \in SL(2,\mathbf R) \implies f(B)=\det B= 1_{\mathbf R^*}=1$.

Now can we write an element of  $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) $  as $AB$ where $A \in GL(2,\mathbf{R}),  B \in SL(2,\mathbf R)$?

Then  we get $f(AB)=\det A \times 1=\det A \in \mathbf R^*$, thus $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow \mathbf R^{*}$ by $AB \mapsto \det A$.

EDIT:

Previous Question: Why do author(s) use less strong statement?
Of course if  $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) = GL(2,\mathbf{R}) $ then  $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R})$ gives the same output as $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) $ which belogs to ${\mathbf R^*}$, thus, $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R})$ is in ${\mathbf R^*}$, which is stronger than saying $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) \cong \mathbf{R}^*$.

Then why do author(s) go for $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) \cong \mathbf{R}^*$?

What is the significance of choosing $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) \cong \mathbf{R}^*$ rather than using $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) =GL(2,\mathbf{R})$? What am I missing here?

Another example is that often I found that we can say directly that $H_{i+1}= \rm Ker \; g$ but author(s) used $H_{i+1}\subseteq \rm Ker \; g$ ([see Question 1 in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256432/850314)), obviously $H_{i+1}= \rm Ker \; g$ does not contradict $H_{i+1}\subset \rm Ker \; g$ but why do author go for the weaker statement?

Comment: The objects in any algebraic $A/B$ are equivalence classes of elements of $A$.  In what sense should we pretencd that $\Bbb{R}^*$ is a set of equivalence classes of elements of $\mathrm{GL}(2,\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: Equality means that the two sets consist of the same elements. This is obviously not the case here.

Comment: @kabenyuk you are right I have edited.

Comment: It is not true that $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R}) = GL(2,\mathbf{R})$.  Where did you get this claim from?

Comment: What you have written makes little sense but it appears you may be confusing the quotient $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R})$ with the product set $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) \cdot SL(2,\mathbf{R})$.  These are two totally different objects.

Comment: "but why do author go for the weaker statement?" Here we need a concrete example.

Comment: @symplectomorphic what is an element of $GL(2,\mathbf{R}) / SL(2,\mathbf{R})$? how do we write that?

Comment: @EricWofsey See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2985117/850314: For any coset $gH$, pick an arbitrary representative $x=gh$ where $h\in H$.
 Define $\phi(gH) = \det (g)$. This is well-defined (ie independent of $h\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of $GL(2)$ are the multiples of the identity matrix $I$ which can easily be calculated, so $C(GL(2))\cong \mathbf{R}^*.$ The factor $GL(2)/SL(2)$ has to be one-dimensional: $4-3=1$ so $GL(2)/SL(2)\cong \mathbf{R}^*.$ The commutator group $[GL(2),GL(2)]\subseteq SL(2)$ because of the determinant. From $SL(2)=[SL(2),SL(2)]\subseteq [GL(2),GL(2)]$ we get the other inclusion. The first equality holds because $SL(2)$ has only the three normal subgroups $\{SL(2),\{I\},\{\pm I\}\}$ and is not abelian, so that the normal commutator subgroup of $SL(2)$ is the entire group $SL(2)$. $GL(2)\ncong C(GL(2))\times SL(2)$ because $\mathbf{R}^*\cdot I \subsetneq C(GL(2))\cap SL(2)=\mathbf{R}^*\cdot \{\pm I\},$ i.e. the intersection of the two subgroups is non-trivial. $-I$ makes the difficulties here because it has determinant one and is in the center.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbf{R})=[\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbf{R}),\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbf{R})]$ and $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbf{R})/\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbf{R})\cong \operatorname{C}(\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbf{R}))\cong \mathbf{R}^*$

Comment: This isn't quite right, since $\det(\det M \cdot M')=\det(M)^2\cdot \det M'$... That is, the center is not quite a complementary subgroup to $SL(2)$ inside $GL(2)$...

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you. I corrected the notation.

Comment: Can you give detail explanations for first 2 lines or reffer me a book where I can find those explanations myselfs?

Comment: For linear algebraic groups in general I would recommend Humphreys with the same title. Not sure whether general group theory is necessary here. I've learnt it from van der Waerden but this is a bit old fashioned.